# How do I debug in Moodle as a developer?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, moodle, developer-tools

I am working on moodle especially in manipulation data. I want to share my experience as developer for **debugging in moodle**. May this will help you to save your time on google searching.

Comment: If I Google "Moodle debugging", the very first link is to the latest version of the document that you copied a chunk out of in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a search on google finally i found documentation about this. 
you can add this on your config.php

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
// @error_reporting(1023);  // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1'); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = 32767;         // DEBUG_DEVELOPER // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
// for Moodle 2.0 - 2.2, use:  $CFG->debug = 38911;  
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;   // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!

// You can specify a comma separated list of user ids that that always see
// debug messages, this overrides the debug flag in $CFG->debug and $CFG->debugdisplay
// for these users only.
$CFG->debugusers = '2';
```

https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Debugging#In_config.php

Comment: What is `32767`? A userid?

Answer (score 0):

Your root folder / config.php

uncomment last lines
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!